# Write a function that returns a subset of a string between one index and another without using built-in function

Tags: javascript

Write a function that returns a subset of a string between one index and another. Without using any built-in function: `substr`, `substring`, `slice`, `splice`...

Hi guys, can you help me with this, the code went wrong and i don't know how to fix it.Thanks
Example (("abcd",1,10) return "bcd")
I alter it thanks to you guys. But it still missing something, like it only work if the substring is the start of the string.

```js
function func3(str, indexStart, indexEnd) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = indexStart; i < indexEnd && i < str.length; i++) {
    var x = str.charAt(i);
    if (indexEnd > i > indexStart) {
      var y = str.charAt(i);
    } 
    }
    result += x + y
  }
  return result
}

console.log(func3('abcdxyz', 1, 10));
```

Comment: For starters if condition in your loop states `i` must be less than `indexEnd` ... why would you need to check later that `i>indexEnd`? Hint: each iteration should add a character to `result`

Answer (score 1):

You could check if `i` is not only smaller than the given end, but also if the length is smaller than the length of the string.

```js
function func3(str, indexStart, indexEnd) {
    var result = "";
    for (var i = indexStart; i < indexEnd && i < str.length; i++) {
        result += str[i];
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(func3("abcd", 1, 10));
```

An even shorter approach by taking the minimum length in advance.

```js
function func3(str, indexStart, indexEnd) {
    var result = "",
        i,
        l = Math.min(indexEnd, str.length);

    for (i = indexStart; i < l; i++) {
        result += str[i];
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(func3("abcd", 1, 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = "";
for (var i=indexStart; i < indexEnd; i++){
    result += str.charAt(i);
}
return result
```

Comment: Assumes indexEnd is less than string length

Answer (score 0):

If `prototype` functions ain't your thing, this may be what you are looking for:

```js
function charBetween(str, start, end) {
  let res = '';
  if (start > end) return res;
  while (str[start] !== undefined && start <= end) {
    res += str[start];
    start++;
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(charBetween("This is a test.", 9, 100));
```

I have also added a prototype function to `String`'s if you would like to use it. By doing this you may call this function like so:

```js
String.prototype.charBetween = function(start, end) {
  'use strict'; // `this` refers to an object without strict set. 
  let res = '';
  if (start > end) return res;
  while (this[start] !== undefined && start <= end) {
    res += this[start];
    start++;
  }
  return res;
}

console.log("This is a test.".charBetween(9, 100));
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

```
    function func3(str, indexStart, indexEnd) {
        var result="";
        for (var i=Math.max(0, indexStart); i<=indexEnd || i>str.lengths; i++) {
            result += str.charAt(i);
        }
        return result;
    }

    console.log(func3("abcd", 1, 10));
    console.log(func3("abcd", -1, 10));
    console.log(func3("abcd", 2, 2));
    console.log(func3("abcd", 7, 10));
```

Answer (score -2):

You are declaring two variables `x` and `y` and `y` may not be present every time.

```js
function func3(str,indexStart,indexEnd){
  var result = "";
  var x;
  for (var i=indexStart; i < indexEnd; i++){
    x = str.charAt(i);
    if (indexEnd>i && i > indexStart){
       x =str.charAt(i);
    }
    else if (i>indexEnd){
       break;
    }
    result += x
  }
  return result
}
      
console.log(func3("abcd",1,3))
```

A simpler way is to get the the min value out of length of string an end index. And then loop only upto that.

```js
function func3(str,indexStart,indexEnd){
  var result = "";
  let len = Math.min(str.length,indexEnd)
  for (var i=indexStart; i < len; i++){
    result += str[i];
  }
  return result
}
      
console.log(func3("abcd",1,10))
```

Comment: @huutri `func3("abcdxyz",2,10);`